# Fixed y-axis width in flex columnchart

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, charts

I'm using a flex columnchart to display data, that changes at runtime. It works perfectly, except the fact, that the y-axis with is automatically resized when the values goes under 1.
For example first the values of the charts are between 0 and 10. The y-axis now has labels like 0,1,2,3,4...10. If the values are going under 1 the labels are updated to 0.0, 0.1, 0.2...1.0. And because of the width of the labels, the group with the charts is resized.
It looks like the chart is "jumping".

So, I need a way, to set a fixed width of the y-axis of the chart.
Hope, I make myself clear and anyone knows a solution.

thx,
tux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using an own label function, so that the string has always the same length. Not so clean, but i worked!

```
public static function formatLabel(labelValue:String, previousValue:String, axis:IAxis) : String
{
    var values : Array = labelValue.split(".");
    if(!values[1])
    {
        if(values[0].length==1)
            values[1] = "0";
    }
    return values.join(".");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ColumnChart has a maxLabelWidth property that ought to help. I do find it strange that it doesn't have stepSize like some less complicated Flex controls.